# How to use wxWidgets in Mac

Tags: macos, wxwidgets, compilation

I am completely newbie in wxWidget and want to learn about this library. I've try to install with "make" command and try to make a program (using the g++ stuff) and no success. I've try to use http://max.berger.name/howto/wxWidgets/wxWidgets_Eclipse.jsp#d43e34 but no succes either.

So actually how to use wxWidgets and compile a program? Am I have to write my own Makefile? Am I have to put the source code in the wxWidgets installation?

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Mac there's two ways: `use ./configure && make && make install` in your wxWidgets download folder, or use Xcode to build wxWidgets. Both these ways are documented on the wxWidgets wiki:

- [Compiling wxWidgets with Xcode](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_with_Xcode)
- [Compiling wxWidgets with configure && make && make install](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_using_the_command-line_%28Terminal%29)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this - http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/faqmac.htm#buildx ?

Have no personal experience on mac.. I've only used it on Windows.